# The movetoElement get freeze. is there any way to verify if it freeze or no

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to perform a hover but the moveToElement is not working, gets stuck, and is not showing an error.

```
Actions builder = TestEnv.driverManager.getNewAction();
logger.debug("pass the element" + builder);
builder.moveToElement(webElement)
.build().perform();
```

is there any way to maybe timeout the `moveToElement()` because it is getting stuck and is not doing the next line?

Comment: Check browser console . Same happing with manual process

Comment: the manual goes fine,I created a mouse so I can see the move and stay  on the same place

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute an Actions, it has to be followed with `.perform()`.
In your example, it would be `builder.moveToElement(webElement).perform();`